# Angularjs $http GET json data not displayed

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I'm trying to get json data through json server. I create an angularjs application and generate a fake REST API with json server at http://localhost:3000/records which return json data successfully.
But with $http service I cannot catch the data !

this is my service and controller code:

Service code: contact.service.js

```
   `(function () {
        var app = angular.module("contactApp");
    app.service("contactSvc", contactSvc);

    function contactSvc($http) {

        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/records/"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            var msg = "succès !";
            this.res = response.data.records;
        });
    };})();`
```

code of the controller : contact.controller.js

```
 `(function (){ 
var app = angular.module("contactApp");
app.controller("contactCtrl", contactCtrl);

function contactCtrl(appName,contactSvc) {

    this.applicationName = appName;
    this.contacts = contactSvc.res;
    this.errmsg = contactSvc.msg;

    this.selectContact = function (index) {
        this.selectedContact = this.contacts[index];
    };
}})();`
```

and finaly code of index.html:

```
 `<div  ng-controller="contactCtrl as ctrl">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.contacts" ng-click="ctrl.selectContact($index)">
       {{contact.name.first +" "+contact.name.last}} </li>
     </ul>
    </div>`
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: what do you see when you put console.log(this.contracts);

Comment: thanks for your prompt hep. it show Undefined contact.controller.js:11. !

Answer (score 0):

You should return promise from contactSvcfunction and when's resolved it should return response.data from that function.

```
var contactSvc= angular.module("contactApp").service("contactSvc", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getcontacts: function() {    
            return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/records/')
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("coming from servicejs", response.data);              
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

In your controller you should call the service function and use **`.then`** function to get call it when the getResponders service function resolves the $http.get call and assign the data to $scope.gotData

**`Code`**

```
 myService.getcontacts().then(function(data){
      this.contacts = data.records;
 });
```

Comment: Now the ` console.log("coming from servicejs", response.data)` return the data correctly. but the data is not coming to index.html. Many thx

Comment: Can you post what do you get in the console for console.log(JSON.stringify(data.records));

Comment: I put  console.log(JSON.stringify(data.records)) in the controller and a message 'Undefined contact.controller.js 11 is displayed

Comment: when I put console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); the data was displayed successfully

Comment: Post the data here

Comment: [
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
       "first": "kenneth",
      "last": "walters"
    },
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "zouheir",
      "last": "touati"
    },
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "ali",
      "last": "salhi"
    },
    "id": 3
  }
]

Comment: I am sorry I canncot chat because I'm new to this forum. so it's strange to work with you and not for me ! i cannot not understand why ?

Comment: check if you have referenced the controller and method correctly

Comment: i verified and nothing seems to be wrong: <div class='container' ng-controller="contactCtrl as ctrl">
        <div class='row'>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.repertoire" ng-click="ctrl.selectContact($index)">
                    {{contact.name.first}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: i see you are using ctr.repertoire which should be ctrl.contracts

Comment: Yes I just try to the variable in both html and controller file. but the issue is still here

Comment: I'm sorry I mean I just try to change the variable in both html and controller file. issue is still there.  Many thx

Comment: I think i found the cause error: the URL requested in service code was http://localhost:3000/ which is the json-server. but when i'm trying the URL http://localhost:8080/data/db.json there is another type of error like : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.  could this help to diagnostic, please. Many thx

Comment: which means you need to enable cors on your server side

Comment: OK. but it should be work without manimulte cors. normaly it should work fine with any call to REST service which return a json response. is that true. because i follow a course in youtube channel and did like it says. it's stange. nevermind thank you very much for your help. best regards.